# Shared token between different apps

Tags: react-native

I have different reac-native apps. Is it possible to shared information (a login token) between them? I am using [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to store the token but did not figured out how to share the same keychain between multiple apps.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried setting it in `AsyncStorage`? I would use a DB for this IMO though.

Comment: Just tried sharing between `AsyncStorage` and it's a no go. Which would make complete sense lol